# When Sublime Text3 is used with vintageouse, how do I set the cursor to underline when I enter command mode?

Tags: vim, sublimetext3, sublimetext, vim-plugin, sublime-text-plugin

When entering Command mode in the previous version, the cursor is underlined. After I updated to version 3.2 today, I entered the Command mode and the cursor became a block. How can I change the cursor? Thank you

Comment: do you have the Insert key turned on?